# Weblogic 10.3.3 conflict with HtmlUnit Spring webservice

Tags: spring, exception, weblogic, conflict, htmlunit

Having some trouble getting a screenscraper webservice up and running on a weblogic 10.3.3 app server. I'm using Maven to manage my build, HtmlUnit for my scraping logic and everything is wired through the spring framework. This is my first attempt at developing a webservice!

I have HtmlUnit in my pom.xml as a dependecy as so:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

...and here's my spring-ws-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <sws:annotation-driven />
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.x.ws"/>

        <bean id="addressLookupConfiguration" class="com.x.ws.z.utils.AddressLookupConfiguration"/>

        <sws:interceptors>
            <bean id="interceptor"
                class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
                <property name="schemas">
                    <list>
                        <value>/WEB-INF/AddressLookup.xsd</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
                <property name="validateRequest" value="true" />
                <property name="validateResponse" value="true" />
            </bean>

            <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor">
              <property name="policyConfiguration" value="/WEB-INF/securityPolicy.xml"/>
              <property name="callbackHandlers">
                  <list>
                      <ref bean="callbackHandler"/>
                  </list>
              </property>
          </bean>
        </sws:interceptors>

        <bean id="callbackHandler"
                class="com.x.ws.z.security.AddressLookupValidationCallbackHandler">
                <property name="users">
                    <props>
                        <prop key="x">x</prop>
                        <prop key="x">x</prop>
                        <prop key="x">x</prop>
                    </props>
                </property>
        </bean>
        <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="addressLookup" portTypeName="addressLookup"
            locationUri="http://bob/ws/z/x/addressLookup">
            <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/AddressLookup.xsd" />
        </sws:dynamic-wsdl>
</beans>
```

I can view the generated WSDL and everything looks fine, but when I call my webservice I get:

```
ERROR | 2012-04-12 18:20:01,026 | AddressLookupEndpoint.java:60 | java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z
```

When I call it a second, and each subsequent time I get:

```
ERROR | 2012-04-12 18:20:25,676 | AddressLookupEndpoint.java:60 | java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient
```

Not sure why I get that NoSuchMethod exception the first time, but clearly weblogic isn't finding the HtmlUnit jar (I've confirmed its in WEB-INF/lib of the war file).

I assumed there was a conflict with some jar on the weblogic end so I added the following to my application weblogic.xml

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

However, when I deploy the application the WSDL doesn't get created correctly. The following exception is thrown:

```
ERROR | 2012-04-12 18:03:46,484 | FrameworkServlet.java:314 | Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.DelegatingSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor#0': Cannot create inner bean 'interceptor' of type [org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'interceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.xml.validation.XmlValidationException: Could not create Schema: SAX2 driver class weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader does not implement XMLReader; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
<trunc>
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.DelegatingSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor#0': Cannot create inner bean 'interceptor' of type [org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'interceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.xml.validation.XmlValidationException: Could not create Schema: SAX2 driver class weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader does not implement XMLReader; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
<trunc>
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'interceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.xml.validation.XmlValidationException: Could not create Schema: SAX2 driver class weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader does not implement XMLReader; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
        ... 56 more
Caused by: org.springframework.xml.validation.XmlValidationException: Could not create Schema: SAX2 driver class weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader does not implement XMLReader; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
        at org.springframework.xml.validation.Jaxp13ValidatorFactory.createValidator(Jaxp13ValidatorFactory.java:45)
        at org.springframework.xml.validation.XmlValidatorFactory.createValidator(XmlValidatorFactory.java:92)
<trunc>
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
        at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.xml.validation.SchemaLoaderUtils.loadSchema(SchemaLoaderUtils.java:70)
        at org.springframework.xml.validation.Jaxp13ValidatorFactory.createValidator(Jaxp13ValidatorFactory.java:41)
        ... 63 more
<Apr 12, 2012 6:03:46 PM IST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101017> <[ServletContext@135824637[app:nieAddressLookup module:nieAddressLookup.war path:/ws/nieaddresslookup/v1 spec-version:null]] Root cause of ServletException.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.DelegatingSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor#0': Cannot create inner bean 'interceptor' of type [org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'interceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.xml.validation.XmlValidationException: Could not create Schema: SAX2 driver class weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader does not implement XMLReader; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.DelegatingSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor#0': Cannot create inner bean 'interceptor' of type [org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'interceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.xml.validation.XmlValidationException: Could not create Schema: SAX2 driver class weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader does not implement XMLReader; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:616)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'interceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.xml.validation.XmlValidationException: Could not create Schema: SAX2 driver class weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader does not implement XMLReader; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: org.springframework.xml.validation.XmlValidationException: Could not create Schema: SAX2 driver class weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader does not implement XMLReader; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
        at org.springframework.xml.validation.Jaxp13ValidatorFactory.createValidator(Jaxp13ValidatorFactory.java:45)
        at org.springframework.xml.validation.XmlValidatorFactory.createValidator(XmlValidatorFactory.java:92)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.AbstractValidatingInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractValidatingInterceptor.java:153)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
        at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.xml.validation.SchemaLoaderUtils.loadSchema(SchemaLoaderUtils.java:70)
        at org.springframework.xml.validation.Jaxp13ValidatorFactory.createValidator(Jaxp13ValidatorFactory.java:41)
        at org.springframework.xml.validation.XmlValidatorFactory.createValidator(XmlValidatorFactory.java:92)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

It seems a jar in my application is conflicting with the weblogic xml parser. I removed the xmlParserAPIs jar from my build and redeployed. Now I get the following exception:

```
ERROR | 2012-04-13 11:10:51,316 | FrameworkServlet.java:314 | Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/namespace/QName
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:468)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:129)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.doIt(WebAppServletContext.java:3686)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3650)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2268)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2174)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1446)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/namespace/QName
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:328)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:285)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:253)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:56)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:42)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reset(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.configurePipeline(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.configurePipeline(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
        ... 9 more
<Apr 13, 2012 11:10:51 AM IST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101017> <[ServletContext@135546353[app:nieAddressLookup module:nieAddressLookup.war path:/ws/nieaddresslookup/v1 spec-version:null]] Root cause of ServletException.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/namespace/QName
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/namespace/QName
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:328)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:285)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I can't see how weblogic wouldn't be able to find QName. The weblogic box is a mirror of our production one, we have lots of other webservices running fine on it so it should be configured correctly.

I would appreciate some advice on how to get weblogic to see the HtmlUnit jar, these issues are really exhausting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WL 10.3.3 introduces use of the prefer-application-packages in the weblogic.xml file of a .war rather than just in the weblogic-application.xml of a .ear.

Something like the following should help with the method not found issue.

```
<container-descriptor>
  <prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>org.apache.commons.lang.*</package-name>
  </prefer-application-packages>
</container-descriptor>
```